# C# asp.net Gridview navigate to url in gridview row

Tags: c#, url, gridview

I'm currently working on an in house project, I've created a GridView connected to a SQL table which looks like this:

GridView1

[image: Example image of GridView1]

I created the view content buttons using the following code:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="View Content" CommandName="Select" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ContentID" HeaderText="ContentID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ContentID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Code" HeaderText="Code" SortExpression="Code" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="URL" HeaderText="URL" Visible="true" SortExpression="URL" />                
</Columns>
```

But this is where I am now stuck. **I would like to click on the view content button and have it navigate to the URL on the selected row.**

The `URL` comes from the SQL Table and there is a string so I'd imagine, it would need to be converted first but I could be wrong.

I started to put my code in the following:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewCommandEventArgs x = (GridViewCommandEventArgs)e;
    if (x.CommandName == "Select")
    {
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add your code in `GridView1_RowCommand` event of `gridview`:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
       if (e.CommandName == "Select")
        {
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((BoundField)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
            int index = row.RowIndex;

            string url = (GridView1.Rows[index].FindControl("URL") as BoundField).Text;
            Response.Redirect(url); // url can be from your sql table

        }    
}
```

**Note:** Don't forget to add OnRowCommand event in GrindView `<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" >`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have followed your advice and it now appears to want to do something, i get the following error though.                        
                                                                                                          
         Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.enquirehomepage_aspx' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow'.  Any ideas?

Comment: Cast your `url` from `Label` to `BoundField`.. see my edit

Comment: I have made the suggested change but I get the following error.        **cannot convert type 'system.web.ui.control' to 'system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield'.**  This is after changing `Label` to `BoundField`. Are you familiar with this error? I've tried to research it myself but have found nothing useful in this context.

Comment: use `Control` instead of `BoundField`

Comment: `Control` does not contain a definition for `Text` though.

Answer (score 1):

```
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((BoundField)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
            int index = row.RowIndex;

            string url = (GridView1.Rows[index].FindControl("URL") as BoundField).Text;
            Response.Redirect(url); // url can be from your sql table
```

So i made the change. Unfortunately, `BoundField` does not contain a definition for `NamingContainer`.

Also, `GridView1.Rows[index].FindControl("URL") as BoundField` fails due to the following error, **cannot convert type 'system.web.ui.control' to 'system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion or null type conversion.**

Comment: so you have to convert your gridview in `templatefield` to work with my answer :)